# Why initial state is not synced from previous tab in react redux-toolkit app using redux-state-sync?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have an example [stackblitz application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uadxdg?file=src%2Fstore.ts) using [redux-state-sync](https://github.com/AOHUA/redux-state-sync?tab=readme-ov-file) that describes the problem that a window does not get initial state from other window like it should when function [`initStateWithPrevTab`](https://github.com/AOHUA/redux-state-sync?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-use) is called.

Expected behavior (confirmed also in my old Angular app):

1. Open a "main window" with route `/` and dispatch a state change
2. Open another app window with a route `/properties/`
3. The /properties/ window asks for the initial state
4. The main window replies with it's state (a state has been changed in step 1)
5. /properties/ window receives the (changed) state from main window.

However my linked example app works like this:

1. Open a "main window" with route `/` and dispatch a state change
2. Open another app window with a route `/properties/`
3. Now the /properties/ window has initial state without the change dispatched in main window in step 1.
4. Dispatch another state change in main window
5. The state change is now synced to the /properties/ window

The `/properties/`-window receives the entire state from "main window" and it dispatches [`receiveIniteState`](https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync/blob/master/src/syncState.js) but it doesn't have any effect.

So ONLY the initial state from previous tab ("main window") is not synced to the new window (/properties/). All the state changes AFTER the /properties/ window is opened are synced without problem. The code looks like this:

store.ts

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    appProperties: appPropertiesReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(createStateSyncMiddleware()),
});
initStateWithPrevTab(store);
```

AppProperties.slice.ts

```
interface AppPropertiesState {
  propertiesId: string;
}
const initialState: AppPropertiesState = {
  propertiesId: '0',
};
const propertiesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app-properties',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setPropertiesId(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.propertiesId = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
export const { setPropertiesId } = propertiesSlice.actions;
export const selectPropertiesId = (state: RootState) =>
  state.appProperties.propertiesId;
export const getInitialState = propertiesSlice.getInitialState;
export default propertiesSlice.reducer;
```

index.ts

```
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App name="StackBlitz" />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx

```
export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<MainView />} />
            <Route path="properties" element={<Properties />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

MainView.tsx

```
let i = 0;
export function MainView() {
  function onSetPropertiesId(): void {
    store.dispatch(setPropertiesId((++i).toString()));
  }
  const propertiesId = useSelector(selectPropertiesId);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Click the button increment propertiesId</p>
      <button onClick={onSetPropertiesId}>Increment</button>
      <p>Properties Id : {propertiesId}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Properties.tsx

```
export function Properties() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<ReactNode | undefined>(undefined);
  const propertiesId = useSelector(selectPropertiesId);
  useEffect(() => {
    setContent(<span>PropertiesId : {propertiesId}</span>);
  }, [propertiesId]);
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```

How to reproduce it in the example [stackblitz application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uadxdg?file=src%2Fstore.ts):

1. Open https://stackblitz-starters-uadxdg.stackblitz.io
2. Press the Increment button -> now the value in state for this window is 1.
3. Open https://stackblitz-starters-uadxdg.stackblitz.io/properties -> now the value is 0 even though it should get the initial value (1) from the 1st window AND NOT from it's local initial state (0).

After that syncing works. So the question is that why 2nd window doesn't init the state from previous window even though `initStateWithPrevTab` is called? As mentioned before the initial state syncing in the library works and I have no problem in my old Angular app.

Comment: Is this basically a duplicate of your previous [post](/q/77921155/8690857) but with less details?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying or hoping to get from an instance of your app running in one browsing context from another instance of your app running in a different browsing context? Please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish here and what the specific issue/problem is.

Comment: The problem is quite clearly stated in this post. It says that initial state is not synced to the other app instance / tab / window.  The question is: why this doesn't work? Also does using terms like " trying or hoping" imply that you think https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-state-sync package doesn't work like it's supposed to? I've been using the library in angular app for years and it works there perfectly.

Comment: Also the original post had lots of details that had nothing to do with the actual issue (again: initial state not synced) so I created minimal reproducible example for this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by combining reducers and moving initStateWithPrevTab to App.tsx.

store.ts

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: withReduxStateSync(
    combineReducers({
      appProperties: appPropertiesReducer
    })
  ),
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(createStateSyncMiddleware()),
});
```

App.tsx

```
export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  // function call moved here
  initStateWithPrevTab(store);
  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<MainView />} />
            <Route path="/properties" element={<Properties />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering revolves around **initial state synchronization** between different tabs in a React Redux Toolkit app using `redux-state-sync`. The expected behavior is that when a new tab is opened, it should receive the initial state from the previously opened tab. However, you're observing that the initial state is not synced as expected.

Here's a breakdown of the issue and potential solutions:

1. **Expected Behavior (Desired Flow):**

   - Open a "main window" with the route `/` and dispatch a state change.
   - Open another app window with the route `/properties/`.
   - The `/properties/` window should ask for the initial state.
   - The main window should reply with its state (which has been changed in step 1).
   - The `/properties/` window should receive the (changed) state from the main window.
2. **Actual Behavior (Observed Issue):**

   - Open a "main window" with the route `/` and dispatch a state change.
   - Open another app window with the route `/properties/`.
   - Now the `/properties/` window has an initial state without the change dispatched in the main window (step 1).
   - If you dispatch another state change in the main window, it is synced to the `/properties/` window.
   - The `/properties/` window receives the entire state from the "main window," but the initial state from the previous tab ("main window") is not synced to the new window.
3. **Code Analysis:**

   - Your `store.ts` configuration seems correct, including the use of `createStateSyncMiddleware()`.
   - The issue might be related to how the initial state is handled in your `propertiesSlice`.
   - Ensure that the `initStateWithPrevTab(store)` function is called correctly.
4. **Possible Solutions:**

   - **Check initStateWithPrevTab:**

     - Verify that the `initStateWithPrevTab(store)` function is called at the right place (e.g., during app initialization).
   - **Inspect propertiesSlice:**

     - Review your `propertiesSlice` and ensure that the initial state is correctly set.
     - Confirm that the `propertiesId` value is being updated as expected.
   - **Debugging:**

     - Use browser developer tools to inspect Redux state changes and actions.
     - Log relevant information during the state synchronization process to identify any discrepancies.
5. **Additional Considerations:**

   - Ensure that your Redux store is properly configured across different tabs.
   - Check if there are any conflicting middleware or custom logic affecting state synchronization.

Remember that Redux state synchronization across tabs can be tricky due to browser limitations and timing issues. Make sure to thoroughly test your implementation and consider alternative approaches if needed.

Hope this helps you!!